# Deserializing a single XML stack into multiple objects

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-deserialization

I'm working on a project that returns a single XML block, as such:

```
<root>
  <x_val />
  <x_val2 />
  <x_addr1 />
  <x_addr2 />
  <x_city />
  <x_state />
  <x_country />
  <x_zip />
</root>
```

In this project, I can make multiple calls that return various pieces of information, but most of them will contain the address information at the bottom.

When writing my C# classes, I'd prefer not to have to create properties for every single one of these nodes in every single response object I create. Instead, I'd prefer to define a single Address object, for use as such:

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
[Serializable]
public class ReturnItem1
{
    [XmlElement("x_val")]
    public string FirstValue{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement("x_val2")]
    public string SecondValue{ get; set; }

    public Address AddressInfo { get; set; }

    public ReturnItem1()
    {
        AddressInfo = new Address();
    }
}

public class Address
{
    [XmlElement("x_addr1")]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("x_addr2")]
    public string Address2 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("x_city")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("x_state")]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("x_country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("x_zip")]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
}
```

When deserializing, I'm performing the following logic (response is of type XElement):

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ReturnItem1));
var returnObject = (ReturnItem1)serializer.Deserialize(response.CreateReader());
```

The values for FirstValue and SecondValue are populated within returnObject, but the properties within Address are always null.

I've tried adding the [XmlRoot("root)"] attribute to the Address class, but that didn't work. Neither did setting the XmlElement attribute on the Address property in ReturnItem1 to "root" or any other of the node names.

Is there any way using this approach to deserialize a single XML node into an object with one or more sub-objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to deserialize the XML into the object using TAMTAM's suggestion, as follows:

```
[DataContract(Name="root", Namespace = "")]
public class ReturnItem1
{
    [DataMember(Name = "x_val", Order = 0)]
    public string FirstValue { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "x_val2", Order = 1)]
    public string SecondValue { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "x_addr1", Order = 2)]
    private string _address;

    [DataMember(Name = "x_addr2", Order = 3)]
    private string _address2;

    [DataMember(Name = "x_city", Order = 4)]
    private string _city;

    [DataMember(Name = "x_state", Order = 5)]
    private string _state;

    [DataMember(Name = "x_country", Order = 6)]
    private string _country;

    [DataMember(Name = "x_zip", Order = 7)]
    private string _postalCode;

    public Address AddressInfo { get; set; }

    [OnDeserialized()]
    void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
    {
        AddressInfo = new Address
        {
            Address1 = _address,
            Address2 = _address2,
            PostalCode = _postalCode,
            City = _city,
            Country = _country,
            State = _state
        };
    }
}
```

I finally reached a solution I can live with. ReturnItem1 extends a base class that contains a List of AdditionalAttributesToDeserialize. Then in the OnDeserialized method of ReturnItem1, I add "AddressInfo" to that list. After deserializing the base object, I then iterate through that list, using Reflection to find the property and the property's type, and for each entry the program creates a new DataContractSerializer and deserializes the property before using Reflection to set the property's value to the newly-deserialized object. It's a bit of a brute force approach, and it is prone to fat fingering the property name when adding it to the AdditionalPropertiesToDeserialize list, but it does allow me to define my objects and attributes in one place and reuse them at will.

Answer (score 0):

Try using private members matching the XML elements and a public Address property encapsulating them. See this example:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6exf3h2k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but the OnDeserialized method is never invoked. I tried OnDeserializing as well just in case, but no dice.

Comment: Well that's strange, could you please post the full code?

Comment: I got it to work by adding the Order property to each of the DataMember tags, since apparently the deserializer expects those to be there if properties are not in alphabetical order. However, I'm still not satisfied with the result (see post below).